# Why remount of /proc/sys is not global or does not persist in network namespace inside LXC

Tags: proc, lxc, sysctl, network-namespaces

I have host running RHEL-7.2. Inside that running LXC. Inside LXC creating network namespaces. Inside the namespace changing `sysctl` variables was failing (as root):

```
$ ip netns add testns
$ ip netns exec testns bash
$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6": Read-only file system
```

If I remount `/proc/sys` for RW in a shell and then `sysctl -w` inside same shell, then it does work.

```
$ ip netns exec testns bash
$ mount -o remount,rw /proc/sys
$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

I then start 2nd shell and enter netns and `/proc/sys` appears Read-ONLY for that shell, but remains writable within the 1sh shell. This puzzles me. The affect of changing values by first shell is visible to the second shell.

I was trying to add remounting to the provisioning script, but this issue gets in the way.

```
$ ip netns exec testns sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6": Read-only file system

$ ip netns exec testns sh -c \
>   'mount -o remount,rw /proc/sys && sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1'
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

$ ip netns exec testns sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6": Read-only file system
```

Note that I can do this `sysctl` change on host and in LXC's default namespace without any problems. If I create a namespace on the host directly I do not have this problem. I only run into `/proc/sys` being read-only inside the namespace inside LXC.

My questions here are:

**Q1**. I would like `/proc/sys` inside the namespace inside LXC to remain permanently mounted with RW so I can set sysctl vars anytime.

**Q2**. I would like to understand why it behaves the way it does. It seems `/proc/sys` mount is somehow per process, or per `setns` system call? `man ip-netns` talks about bind mount for `/etc/netns/<name>/file` but I don't see anything about `/proc`. Did I miss something obvious?

**Update**

I found what is most likely to be the answer to my **Q2**.
First experimentally and then in `man ip-netns`:

> ip netns exec automates handling of this configuration,
>   file convention for network namespace unaware applications,
>   by creating a mount namespace and bind mounting
>   all of the per network namespace configure files
>   into their traditional location in `/etc`.

So every time `ip netns exec` creates a new mount namespace but `/proc/sys` happens to become the victim of whatever mount options it got where ever it got them from. My best guess is I need to find what causes `ip netns exec` to mount bind `/proc/sys` in read only mode under LXC, which probably will answer my question Q1.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works for me.
This solution might be bad idea for those that care about security such as preventing container interfering with the host.
I do not really understand full consequences of my solution.
I run only my own code inside LXCs with Jenkins tests, so for me it's not an issue.

I found here: https://libvirt.org/drvlxc.html#fsmounts :

> The following special mounts are setup by libvirt
>
> ```
> /proc/sys the host "/proc/sys" bind-mounted read-only
> ```

I still don't understand why inside default network namespace inside LXC I can set `sysctl` but inside other network namespaces I can not.

I added explicit `/proc/sys` mount in the container config XML:

```
<devices>
...
  <filesystem type='mount' accessmode='passthrough'>
    <source dir='/proc/sys/'/>
    <target dir='/proc/sys/'/>
  </filesystem>
```

This allowed me to set `sysctl` both inside the LXC container default and additional namespaces.
I was afraid that setting inside LXC would also affect the host, but it does not.
Now all network namespaces (host, LXC default, LXC custom) have their independent writable (by root) `sysctl` variables without having to remount every time. Or at least that what `sysctl` query reports.